# Dask not efficient on concatenating large pandas dataframes and gives Memory Error

Tags: python, pandas, dask

At first, I tried typical concatenation of pandas dataframe:

```
df=pd.concat([df,df_filtered2],axis=1,sort=False)
```

but it gave the error:

```
/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py:84: UserWarning: Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete. Attempting to use lzma compression will result in a RuntimeError.
  warnings.warn(msg)
/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py:84: UserWarning: Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete. Attempting to use lzma compression will result in a RuntimeError.
  warnings.warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process_data_interpolation.py", line 435, in <module>
    df=pd.concat([df,df_filtered2],axis=1,sort=False)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 255, in concat
    sort=sort,
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 335, in __init__
    obj._consolidate(inplace=True)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5270, in _consolidate
    self._consolidate_inplace()
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5252, in _consolidate_inplace
    self._protect_consolidate(f)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5241, in _protect_consolidate
    result = f()
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5250, in f
    self._data = self._data.consolidate()
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 932, in consolidate
    bm._consolidate_inplace()
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 937, in _consolidate_inplace
    self.blocks = tuple(_consolidate(self.blocks))
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1913, in _consolidate
    list(group_blocks), dtype=dtype, _can_consolidate=_can_consolidate
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 3323, in _merge_blocks
    new_values = new_values[argsort]
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (41, 156082680) and data type float64
```

so I tried Dask:

```
df = dd.concat([df,df_filtered2],axis=1)
```

but it also gave me the MemoryError:

```
/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py:84: UserWarning: Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete. Attempting to use lzma compression will result in a RuntimeError.
  warnings.warn(msg)
/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py:84: UserWarning: Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete. Attempting to use lzma compression will result in a RuntimeError.
  warnings.warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process_data_interpolation.py", line 443, in <module>
    df = dd.concat([df,df_filtered2],axis=1)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/multi.py", line 1045, in concat
    dfs = _maybe_from_pandas(dfs)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 4465, in _maybe_from_pandas
    for df in dfs
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 4465, in <listcomp>
    for df in dfs
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/io.py", line 209, in from_pandas
    for i, (start, stop) in enumerate(zip(locations[:-1], locations[1:]))
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/io.py", line 209, in <dictcomp>
    for i, (start, stop) in enumerate(zip(locations[:-1], locations[1:]))
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1424, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2137, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_slice_axis(key, axis=axis)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1308, in _get_slice_axis
    return self._slice(indexer, axis=axis, kind="iloc")
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 166, in _slice
    return self.obj._slice(obj, axis=axis, kind=kind)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3371, in _slice
    result = self._constructor(self._data.get_slice(slobj, axis=axis))
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 755, in get_slice
    bm._consolidate_inplace()
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 937, in _consolidate_inplace
    self.blocks = tuple(_consolidate(self.blocks))
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1913, in _consolidate
    list(group_blocks), dtype=dtype, _can_consolidate=_can_consolidate
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 3323, in _merge_blocks
    new_values = new_values[argsort]
MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (41, 156082680) and data type float64
```

what else can I try? I am running Python script on linux node with 128GB of RAM memory. In my case the size of one of pandas dataframe after dropping unnecesary columns and converting some columns to integer is 44.48 GB.

Comment: Maybe swap file can help you.

Comment: Is it possible to merge instead of concat? Then it looks like the error appears after  using `.compute()` what if you try to save `to_parquet` instead of compute?

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered in the Dask Best Practices documentation:

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html#load-data-with-dask